# Windows backup loaded to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, backup, files, transfer

I have a backup copy of my Windows 7 machine I made before I converted to Ubuntu. Is there a utility that I can use to load it onto the machine now, even though I'm only running Ubuntu? Please help I need these files back!

***Update***

I used the Windows back-up utility that came installed. I can view all the files on my external that I used in .zip folders but when I unzip them they're strewn about randomly and in invalid formats

Comment: In what format is the backup? How is it stored?

Comment: I used the Windows back-up utility that came installed. I can view all the files on my external that I used in .zip folders but when I unzip them they're strewn about randomly and in invalid formats.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall a Windows Machine, either in a program such as Virtual Box, or on the physical hardware.

To install in Virtual Box, follow these [instructions](http://goo.gl/tm2LZ) (they are a little dated, but good enough to know how to install it.)

To install Windows on your actual machine, follow these [instructions](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub/Ripristino&act=url).

You then need to follow the instructions provided by Microsoft to use the recovery program Windows 7 has - found [here](http://goo.gl/I8Oqe).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what kind of backup, a reasonable method for this is to install software that will allow you to use Windows as a virtual machine on top of your Ubuntu installation - perhaps with Virtual Box. After installing this, you can then install Windows 7 as a virtual machine. And, when Windows 7 has been installed, use could then use your backup as you might on non-virtual Windows.